# phantomjs works only on windows

Tags: linux, phantomjs, headless-browser

I have found some strange issue. I'm using PhantomJs v2.1.1 on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to open page https://my.avast.com and under Windows it has succeeded but on Ubuntu it has failed. 
Also I tried to run example *.js script added to phantomjs2.1.1-*-.tar.gz file, e.g.

```
phantomjs responsive-screenshot.js https://my.avast.com png
```

but it has not succeeded - only images without background and with text `Loading`
have been written.

Could you propose workaround for this situation?

My main goal is to login to avast.com page under headless linux.

Comment: `phantomjs works only on windows` usually due to an SSL error, that's why i suggest you to use the `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` command-line option, `--ssl-protocol=any --debug=true` may not be necessary, but may also be useful.

Comment: Exactly it has helped me to solve this problem. I have googled some informations about it and it looks like this is an old issue. Probably it will not be fixed in nearest future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run with: `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --debug=true`

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --debug=true responsive-screenshot.js https://my.avast.com png
```

You need to use [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) callback, to find out, what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much. Failure was caused by SSL error, wich I displayed by using this [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) callback, and this is the output:  
  
`SSL Error: "The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found"
SSL Error: "The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose"`

Those switches helped me to display this page.  
I found that this error occured even in 2013. It is caused by some modules used in Linux version of PhantomJS?